# Integrating Ckeditor Custom Online Build Into Elixir Phoenix Project Fails

Tags: phoenix-framework, ckeditor5

I went to the ckeditor website and created a custom build, downloaded it and integrated it into the node modules of the assets folder. I then import it like this in the app.js file:

```
import * as InlineEditor from '../node_modules/ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor.js';
```

and try to use this as

```
export const Editor = {
    mounted() {
    if (document.querySelector( '#editor' )) {
        InlineEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ))
        .catch( error => {
            console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: InlineEditor.create is not a function
```

Obviously, the ckeditor online builder does not specify how to integrate their custom builds into projects. Is anyone familiar with this problem and can anyone devise a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The thing is that the custom build obviously comes with the Editor being a parent to three children, namely "default", "Editor", and "EditorWatchdog". Just put in Editor.Editor.create and it worked.